# Negative correlation but positive beta value

Tags: regression, correlation

I got a negative correlation (Pearson correlation) between two variables but a positive beta coefficient of one variable predicting the other in multiple hierarchical linear regression. Is it acceptable? Please justify it with research evidence and literature

Comment: In addition to the worthy answer by @PeterFlom, you might find my answer to this question illuminating: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89547/what-is-the-purpose-of-precision-variables/337129#337129

Comment: Also: Welcome to CV!

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason that this is not possible. It follows from the nature of multiple regression, which controls for variables, which correlation does not do. See any decent book on multiple regression.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful insight